# file extention unknown

Tags: java, intellij-idea, graphql

I am studying GraphQL but i am facing a silly issue which i can't figure out.
Whenever i create a new file in the resources folder and give it an extension of **.graphqls** intelliJ doesn't recognize it.

I have the following 3 dependencies in my POM:

- graphql-spring-boot-starter
- graphql-java-tools
- graphiql-spring-boot-starter

Any idea of why this is happening?

Thank you all in advance

Comment: Where did you find that IntelliJ IDEA supports GraphQL?

Comment: I am following an online course. The teacher just creates the file and intelliJ recognizes it straight away giving it the right icon

Comment: The teacher either has the custom file type configured, a third-party plug-in installed or is using TextMate files support for the syntax highlighting: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/textmate.html . IntelliJ IDEA has no support for this file type out of the box.

Comment: @CrazyCoder The GraphQL IntelliJ plugin has a long history - https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8097-graphql/versions. Really didn't it support `graphqls` files back in January 2020 when you wrote your comment?

Comment: @HonzaZidek Didn't my comment mention a third-party plug-in is possibly handling this file type? I just stated that it's not supported out of the box.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Oh, you are right, I somehow have not noticed that the GraphQL plugin is the *third-party's* :) I think it comes bundled with the IDEA installation and I somehow subconsciously considered it as the JetBrains solution :) Anyway, you could have turned your comment into a full-sized answer, such as "install this or that plugin", because this *would be* a legit answer to the OP's question. There was another guy asking the same https://stackoverflow.com/q/74723550/2886891, I answered him not having been aware of this question.