# IntelliJ IDEA does not recognize the format of GraphQL schema in resources directory

Tags: java, intellij-idea, graphql

I have a Spring Boot project with **GraphQL** in **IntelliJ IDEA**.

ItelliJ IDEA does not recognize the **`.graphqls`** format of the schema, but displays an error message "Image not loaded" instead.

Here how it looks in IntelliJ:

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: I removed all the irrelevant information, and removed the irrelevant `spring-boot` tag. The problem is **not** related to Spring Boot and to the Maven configuration, but **only** to IntelliJ IDEA, and all the extra information was just information noise. If you insist on returning your original question, feel free to revert my changes :)

Comment: The changes you made can stay but I find it interesting why was my question not asked before me, why did I have to ask this in 2022.

Comment: Actually, they did asked, almost 3 years ago https://stackoverflow.com/q/59912101/2886891 - but it then remained without an answer :) The plugin has a long history https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8097-graphql/versions, but I don't know since when it supports the graphqls extension. Now I voted to close the other question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the weird icon of your graphqls file

[image]

instead of

[image]

and the weird error message

> **Image** not loaded

[image]

it sounds like IntelliJ Idea considers your file as an image file.

- Check if you have the [GraphQL plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8097-graphql) installed
- Check if you have the file extension properly [registered](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-registering-file-types.html).
  File | Settings | Editor | FileTypes | GraphQL
  It should look like this:

[image]

- If you don't have it like above, search for the icon your IntelliJ marks your `graphqls` file with and find where it is registered wrongly.

Comment: The GraphQL plugin was not installed, I installed it and it worked thank you for the answer.